# Autofac: resolving factory for generics with dynamic type argument

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

Here is the Idea.

```
public interface IGeneralInterface { }
public interface IGenericInterface<T> : IGeneralInterface { }
public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericInterface<T> { }

public class SomeClient
{
    Func<Type, IGeneralInterface> serviceFactory;

    public SomeClient(Func<Type, IGeneralInterface> serviceFactory)
    {
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }
    public void DoSomething<T>()
    {
        var service = serviceFactory(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

With Autofac, how can I inject this service factory into the client, so that the proper service can be resolved when client.DoSomething() is called?

Comment: Are you just trying to resolve a generic class? I don't see why you are trying to mix DI and factory pattern. You can easily do this with each independently.

Comment: Agreed with @ATerry. 1) If you don't need generics and need to resolve specific implementation of `IGeneralInterface` depending on a `Type`, then you could either hand-code it yourself in a factory or use [Autofac's metadata capabilities](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html). 2) If you *do* need generics, then just register the generic interface as per the [associated documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components)